# How can i place the Floating button on particular position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

[click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvMA0.png)

how can i place the as floating button as shown image position. Below is my XML code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rec_summary_recycler_view_inflow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scr"/>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:src="@drawable/down_arrow"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    android:onClick="Scroll" />
```

Comment: remove the current layout_margin and add layout_marginBottom = "40dp"

Comment: Its going bottom end of the screen

Comment: then add marginBottom=40dp and marginEnd = 40dp, adjust the dp's according to your need

Comment: yes got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this lines in fab. change value according to your needs. this lines will sets a fab to right bottom of screen.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
```

Comment: How can i get know the RecyclerView scroll bar visibility true or false

Comment: @RakeshKadadhi please elaborate your question!

Comment: If recyclerview  scroll  is visible true then i want display a button. But how can i get it scroll bar state(visibility true or not )?

Comment: I have tried with the mrecyculerview.getscrollstate();

Answer (score 0):

**use this to hide show the fab on recyclerview scroll**

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
    {
        if (dy > 0 ||dy<0 && fab.isShown())
        {
            fab.hide();
        }
    }

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
{
    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
    {
        fab.show();
    }

    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
}
});
```

Comment: Hi Jenish, How can i make it moveable on screen .

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to your content_layout.xml (id:layout_content) and use app:layout_anchor="@id/layout_content" in your fab layout.

```
<include layout="@layout/content_order_list"
    android:id="@+id/layout_content"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/layout_content"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```